# Stack overflow when playing with Ruby singleton methods in IRB

Tags: ruby, irb

As the subject states, I experienced a *stack overflow* when playing with singleton methods in IRB. Below is the code I've tried:

```
c= C.new
class << c
  def class
    "my class is #{self.class}."
  end
end
```

When I called `c.class`, I got a:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
Maybe IRB bug!
```

I found a reference on how to adjust [stack sizes](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) but don't understand what stack sizes are in the first place.

**Question:** 
Why did I get that error in IRB? Also, how can I continue experimenting with Ruby singleton/class methods?

Comment: You got an infinite recursion, what did you expect?

Comment: you might want to use `def class; "my class is #{super}"; end`

Comment: Thanks scone for the solution to make my call method work! Just realized that it was caused by an infinite recursion. Thanks for pointing that out, Sergio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, there is some thing called `recursion` where a function can call itself. This is what you have unintentionally done in your code.

The second thing, the stack is something which maintains the function call trace. So that when end of recursion or stack level depth has been reached, it can correctly resume the program.

Its something like this:
Say you have function A and function B.

```
function A {
  /* some code */
  B()
  /* some more code */
}

function B {
  return / * something * /
}
```

Your machine basically halts executing A, saves the state of variables in A onto a stack, calls and executes B. When finally B exits, it pops from the stack and resumes executing A.

In that specific example, since you wish to define your own `class` method. The following code should do:

```
def class
  "my class is #{super}"
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanations, Gaurav. You've made it easy for me to understand stacks and answered both questions I posed excellently.

Answer (score 1):

You've created object and defined method `class` for this object. And then in this method you're calling the same method `class` - you've got infinite recursion.

That's why you should avoid using system-depended keywords when you're defining your own methods, in your example it can be like this:

```
class << c
  def klass
    "my class is #{self.class}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, megas. Will try and avoid defining methods that have already been defined in Ruby's core class moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

The stack originates from the memory model of computers.

For every program there is the `heap`and the `stack`.
The heap part is unimportant right now.

When a program calls a function, several things happen.

- The current position of the program is placed on the stack
- The variables of the current scope are placed on the stack

When you leave a function those actions are reversed in reverse order in order to replicate the state of the programm before calling the function.

So when your function calls itself (which it does), it places the String "my class is " and the current programm position on the stack and launches the function again, which does the same.

This goes on for many iterations until you exceed the amount auf stack reserved for your program. (This depends on your operating system and in the end on the amount of ram available and is always finite.)
This is when you get this exception. The system is informing you, that it ran out of stack space.

This usually only happens with recursion, that has no stop condition.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the nice answers explaining how the stack works,

`class` is a reserved keyword in Ruby. The method `Object#class` is an unique exception. You cannot really redefine it.